# Split the screen with two independent scroll bars

Tags: css

I need to split my screen in half horizontally, so I can have an index on one half (`<aside>`), and the content on another (`<article>`). As such, they need to have independent scroll bars, because otherwise the user would need to scroll the very extensive content (`<article>`) just to reach the index (`<aside>`) again, which I don't want to happen -- I want the index (`<aside>`) to be always visible.

Also, there needs to be some part on the top where the title and the description of the page is kept always visible. I managed to solve this using a `position: sticky` on the `<header>`.

This is the best I got so far, with my limited knowledge:

```css
    h1{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    aside {
    float:right;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>"Page Title"</h1>

<aside>
<h2>Index</h2>
<ol>
    <li><a href="#item-01">January</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-02">February</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-03">March</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-04">April</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-05">May</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-06">June</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-07">July</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-08">August</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-09">September</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-10">October</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-11">November</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-12">December</a></li>
</ol>
Footnotes.
</aside>

<article>
<p>This is the very extensive content:</p>
<h2 id="item-01">January</h2>
<h2 id="item-02">February</h2>
<h2 id="item-03">March</h2>
<h2 id="item-04">April</h2>
<h2 id="item-05">May</h2>
<h2 id="item-06">June</h2>
<h2 id="item-07">July</h2>
<h2 id="item-08">August</h2>
<h2 id="item-09">September</h2>
<h2 id="item-10">October</h2>
<h2 id="item-11">November</h2>
<h2 id="item-12">December</h2>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

It should give some visual orientation for you to understand what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @AbhinashMajhi "It" what? The main content + the menu? Yes, horizontally. But vertically, the title of the page must be always visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :)

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;
    height: 40px;
}

aside {
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float:right;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
article{
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>"Page Title"</h1>

<aside>
<h2>Index</h2>
<ol>
    <li><a href="#item-01">January</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-02">February</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-03">March</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-04">April</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-05">May</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-06">June</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-07">July</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-08">August</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-09">September</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-10">October</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-11">November</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item-12">December</a></li>
</ol>
Footnotes.
</aside>

<article>
<p>This is the very extensive content:</p>
<h2 id="item-01">January</h2>
<h2 id="item-02">February</h2>
<h2 id="item-03">March</h2>
<h2 id="item-04">April</h2>
<h2 id="item-05">May</h2>
<h2 id="item-06">June</h2>
<h2 id="item-07">July</h2>
<h2 id="item-08">August</h2>
<h2 id="item-09">September</h2>
<h2 id="item-10">October</h2>
<h2 id="item-11">November</h2>
<h2 id="item-12">December</h2>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```